# VS Code run ipython in debug console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

Is there a way to run an `ipython` like debug console in VC Code that would allow tab completion and other sort of things?

Comment: You could run iPython from VS Code's console, and then use `%run -d code.py` or `%debug my_function()` etc. You will have tab-completion, but no debug-session integration with VS Code like variable inspection, jump to definition, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile, I have become a big fan of [PDB++](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/) debugger for python. It works like the iPython CLI, so I think the question has become obsolete specifically for me, but still may have some value for others.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a desired feature for VS Code but not yet implemented. See this post: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/vscodeJupyter/issues/19

I'm trying to see if one could use the config file of VS Code to define an ipython debug configuration e.g.:

`{
            "name": "ipython",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "pythonPath": "/Users/tsando/anaconda3/bin/ipython"
        }`

but so far no luck. You can see my post in the above link.

Comment: maybe using PDB++ could do?

Comment: @ElDude thanks, do you have a link explaining how to set up PDB++? First time I hear about that terminology

Answer (score 2):

No, currently (unfortunately) not.  Here's an ongoing thread about this on github.  The issue has P1 status, so will hopefully be implemented soon:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6972

Answer (score 0):

the vscode debug console does allow for auto completion ... however, I am not sure if what you wanted was a way to trigger your code from an ipython shell, if so. you can start ipython like so,

```
python -m debugpy --listen 5678 `which ipython`
```

now you can connect to this remote debugger from vscode.

Answer (score 0):

For tab completion you could install pyreadline3:

```
python -m pip install pyreadline3
```

This is not neccessary on Linux, but on Windows it is.